# Signal-to-Noise ratio of multivariate stochastic process from Correlation Matrix

Tags: signal-analysis, noise, random-process, stochastic, array-signal-processing

I'm not in signal processing, I'm from an another discipline. I've derived a simple result which I presume must be well known in SP and I'd like to know whether there's a paper or textbook that has it that I can cite.

Suppose I have an n-dimensional stochastic process

$\mathbf{x}_{t}\;=\;\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
x_{t}^{\left(1\right)} & x_{t}^{\left(2\right)} & \cdots & x_{t}^{\left(n\right)}\end{array}\right]$

where $t$ denotes an observation. Each of the components $j$ is the combination of a signal $x_{t}^{*}$ and some random idiosyncratic noise:

$x_{t}^{\left(j\right)}\;=\;x_{t}^{*}b_{j}+\varepsilon_{t}^{\left(j\right)}\sqrt{1-b_{j}^{2}}$

where $\varepsilon^{(j)}_{t}$ is iid distributed and uncorrelated across the $n$ components.
For convenience, all these  variables are already standardized (mean 0 variance 1).

$b_{j}$ and therefore the signal-to-noise of each $j$ component ( $b_{j}/(1-b^2_{j})$ ) are not observed.

The simple result is: you observe the correlation matrix $\mathbf{R}$ of the $n$ components of $x_{t}$. Then a simple quadratic system gives you the noise-to-signal ratios of each $j$ component of $\mathbf{x}_{t}$ .

Anybody can tell me whether you've seen this result in a paper or textbook?

Thanks!

Comment: may I assume the $b_j$ are $\text{const.}$ and your ${}^*$ is just a "marker" for "this is the underlying value common to all $x_t^{(i)},i=1,\ldots, n$"?

Comment: Yes. Precisely.

Comment: ok... then I don't see why you need a correlation matrix to get your result? If both $x_t^*$ and $\epsilon_t^{(j)}$ have variance 1 and mean 0, then the SNR of that component $x_t^{j}$ is $$\frac{b_j^2}{1-b_j^2}$$ per construction.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for not being clear enough. The whole point is that $b_{j}$ is unobserved. I have amended the question to clarify it. Also, I'm not looking for the answer. I have the answer. I want to confirm that this is a known result and where I can find it.

Comment: yes, but $b_j^2$ is just the non-diagonal entries in your $\mathbf R$?

Comment: mmm no the (i,j) element of $\mathbf{R}$ is given by $b_{i}b_{j}$
Also - $b_{j}$ constant across $t$ but not across entries $j$ otherwise the problem would be trivial

Comment: ah sorry, I was stupid.

Comment: @bbecon: I don't exactly follow your question but check out the kalman filter if ou haven't already because the gain in the kalman filter is the signal to noise ratio by definition. So, although you only have an observation equation (as far as I can tell there is no equation  representing the evolution for state ), maybe you can write your model in kalman filter form by making the state deterministic and the formula will gain will be something you recognize ? This is just a guess.